# Getting Index to accept optional parameters from route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have this in my *Startup.cs* file:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "list",
                template: "{controller=List}/{action=Index}/{username?}");
        });
```

I want this:

> /list/

to return a view.

and this:

> /list/random_username.12334

to return another view.

I have this in my *ListController.cs*:

```
    public IActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "user index";
        } else {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Hello " + username;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

But only the index without parameters work. The other one returns 404.

Comment: Your pattern requires the `/Index`.

Comment: @SLaks What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your route definition.

```
template: "{controller=List}/{action=Index}/{username?}"
```

So an ideal url will be 
`list/index/something` or `list` or 'list/index'. but if you try `list/index` (where you index is the name of a user), how does mvc know you meant the action method name rather than the param value ?

If you really want to support `list/someusername`, you might consider adding an attribute route on your action method.

```
[Route("list/{username}")]
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
  // to do : return something
}
```

Now you can access `yoursite/list/someusername`

Comment: Thank you, that works. But is it bad practice to do that? Ie. use parameters on the index?

Comment: I do not see it as a bad practice. Use as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but for those that stumble over this one, a simple solution if you don't want to add an attribute to every method is to add another route as a failover as per below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "page",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{username?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "List", action = "Index" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "page",
        pattern: "{controller}/{username?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "List", action = "Index" });
});
```

The above goes into the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` method in `Startup.cs`.

`UseEndpoints` is an extension method found in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace.

In the failover route definition, username potentially doesn't need to be optional and may result in faster route handling, I would test it out in your particular scenario and find what works best for you.

Note: The solution I tested this in was running .NET 5, I realise the question was asked mainly for .NET Core 1, however given the age of the question and its prominence in Google, this may help others looking for a solution using the more modern approach.